# Using the posterior probability from Bayes Theorem as the prior in another calculation

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I’ve got a dataset of medical diagnoses -for each encounter I have the list of conditions the patient has. I want to generate a list of diagnoses the patient DOESN’T have (or at least that aren’t listed) that are most likely, given the list they DO have. I think I know how to do this for pairwise analysis, but I want to use information on all the diagnoses the patient has. I apologize in advance for my flagrant abuse of the maths.

Let’s say A is the diagnosis we want to know about (they haven’t been diagnosed with it, but we want to know how likely it is). Let’s say B is the diagnosis they HAVE. (and please correct me if I’m wrong, but…)

p(A) = # cases of A / # of cases total

p(B) = # cases of B / # of cases total

p(B|A) = # cases of A AND B / # cases of A

p(A|B) = (p(A)* p(B|A))/p(B)

So that gives me the posterior probability of A given the diagnosis we have (B). Can I use that as the prior for another diagnosis (C)? -So they've been diagnosed with both B AND C, but I don't have data on p(A|BnC). Would it be:

p(A) = Posterior from above

p(C) = # cases of C / # of cases total

p(C|A) = # cases of C AND A / # cases of A

p(A|C) = (p(A)*p(C|A))/p(C)

I tried doing that, and either I’m doing it wrong or there is a flaw in this reasoning. The results quickly become impossible (>100%). Here’s some real numbers to show the problem.

p(A) = 409/99239 = 0.41%

p(B) = 18006/99239 = 18.14%

p(B|A) = 228/409 = 55.75%

p(A|B) = (0.41%*55.75%)/18.14% = 1.27%

That much makes sense, the prevalence of B in the population that has A is much higher than in the general population, so the posterior is higher than the prior. Then using the posterior as the prior for the next step:

p(A) = 1.27%

p(C) = 1044/99239 = 1.05%

p(C|A) = 15/409 = 3.67%

p(A|C) = (1.27%*3.67%)/1.05% = 4.41%

Hopefully this is enough for someone to key in on my mistake but suffice it to say that by the time you get to p(D) = 0.15%, p(D|A) = 0.73%; and p(E) = 0.30%, p(E|A) = 2.20% the posterior for A goes up to 160%. I really hope there’s a way to avoid having to do the conditional probability of (A|BnCnDnE), because I simply haven’t got that data!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are asking whether the conditional probability P(A|B&C) can be calculated according to the following formula:

P(A|B&C) = P(A|B)P(C|A)/p(C)

In general case, this formula does not hold true. Let us derive when this equality is true. According to Bayes formula,

P(A|B&C) = p(B&C|A)P(A)/P(B&C)

We want this to be equal to

P(A|B)P(C|A)/P(C) = P(A)P(B|A)p(C|A)/(P(B)P(C))

So, your formula can only be applied under the following condition:

P(B|A)P(C|A)/(P(B)P(C)) = P(B&C|A)/P(B&C)

Here is an example where this is not true:
For a point (x,y) uniformly distributed in a unit square [0,1]x[0,1], let B = {x < 0.5}, C = {y < 0.5}, A = {x + y > 1}.
Then P(B|A) = 0.25, P(C|A) = 0.25, P(B&C|A) = 0, so the sides are not equal.

You may want to check out the https://www.coursera.org/learn/probabilistic-graphical-models/home/welcome course, where they describe how a bayesian network called Pathfinder was used for medical diagnosis.